# Why are my basil leaves turning black?

Tags: leaves, basil, wilt

Seeking all the experts out there.

Just while I was going out to water my basil plant just now, I realised that some leaves have developed dark spots as shown in the pictures. I have immediately trimmed the black leaves off, but does anyone know why that has happened and any possible solutions? I hope it doesn't develop to the rest of the plant...

This is my first basil plant, so please give any comments in case I am doing anything incorrectly[image: Image of basil leaf which turned black]
[image: Image of basil plant with black leaves mostly trimmed off]
Thanks in advance.
Ryan

Comment: Overwatering in combination with too little sun can cause basil plants to brown. Could this just be browning leaves rather than blackening?

Comment: Black leaves are how basil plants frown.  Could be almost anything - cold injury if by chance the plant got exposed to ~ 36oF, or even stress from drying out briefly. Btw, your sweet plants would prefer to live in a bigger pot, ideally separately. Then they would have fuller crowns and grow more leaves for you to use. Also you can delay the plant putting most of its energy into seed production then dying back by removing the flower buds.  Other than that it looks like you are providing for them beautifully.

Comment: InColorado I agree with your suggestion, especially about pinching off flower buds. Also, 2 more things: (1) the "leggy" growth form of these plants suggests that it might be receiving too little light, and (2) the yellow/white lower leaves suggests overwatering. Hope some more sun and less water help!